# java RMI error in server

Tags: java

I'm trying to built java rmi to calculate greatest common divisor.In my server file it's indicate error in  below line.
    Registry reg=new LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099)

here with my server file code

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
public class gcdServer {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
        Registry reg=new LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error message it shows? Please *edit* the question and add it.

Comment: The `new` wrong in that place. you call a static method so just: `Registry reg=LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);`

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: And unrelated : class names go UpperCase in Java.

Comment: There is no `Java RMI error` here. There is a trivial Java syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocateRegistry constructor is private, you cannot create instance on it. You need to call the static method createRegistry like so.,

```
 Registry reg =  LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
```

Comment: There is no `LocateRegistry` constructor call in the OP's code.